# Strange CoreImage cropping issues encounter here

Tags: ios, core-graphics, core-image

I have a strange issue where after I cropped a photo from my photo library, it cannot be displayed from the App.  It gives me this error after I run this code:

> ```
>         self.correctedImageView.image = UIImage(ciImage: correctedImage)
> ```
>
> [api] -[CIContext(CIRenderDestination) _startTaskToRender:toDestination:forPrepareRender:error:] The image extent and destination extent do not intersect.

Here is the code I used to crop and display. (inputImage is CIImage)

> ```
>     let imageSize = inputImage.extent.size
>     let correctedImage = inputImage
>         .cropped(to: textObvBox.boundingBox.scaled(to: imageSize) )
>     DispatchQueue.main.async {
>         self.correctedImageView.image = UIImage(ciImage: correctedImage)  
>     }
> ```

More Info: Debug print the extent of the inputImage and correctedImage

> Printing description of self.inputImage: CIImage: 0x1c42047a0 extent [0 0 3024 4032]>
>
> crop [430 3955 31 32] extent=[430 3955 31 32]
>       affine [0 -1 1 0 0 4032] extent=[0 0 3024 4032] opaque
>         affine [1 0 0 -1 0 3024] extent=[0 0 4032 3024] opaque
>           colormatch "sRGB IEC61966-2.1"_to_workingspace extent=[0 0 4032 3024] opaque
>             IOSurface 0x1c4204790(501) seed:1 YCC420f 601 alpha_one extent=[0 0 4032 3024] opaque

Funny thing is that when I put a breakpoint, using Xcode, i was able to preview the cropped image properly.  I'm not sure what this extent thing is for CIImage, but UIMageView doesn't like it when I assign the cropped image to it. Any idea what this extent thing does?

Comment: CoreImage operates on an infinite plane. The extent is the rectangle in that plane that actually contains the image data you care about.

Comment: How do I change the extent??

Comment: When I apply that to a uiimageview it will not let me

Comment: The call to `.cropped(to:)` is setting the extent. You're setting it to `textObvBox.boundingBox.scaled(to: imageSize)`.

Comment: So why is it that I cannot display it on an UIimageView?

Comment: I don't know. I've never tried displaying a `CIImage` in a `UIImageView` so I don't know why it would produce that error. Sorry.

Comment: I mean when a developer wants to operate a ciimage it must eventually be displayed on screen, so how does others do it, I thought it should have just worked.

Comment: Well, you can always use the `CIContext` to render the `CIImage` to a bitmap.

Comment: I'm not sure if I do it the exact same as @KevinBallard, but I create a `CIContext` - careful, those are expensive (read: creating one takes processing time), try to do it once and use it for everything - then I use `CIContext.createCGImage(CIImage, from: CIExtent)` and then finally `UIImage(cgImage:)`. I choose this method because I render things onto the screen using a `GLKView` (which uses the GPU) instead of a `UIImageView` (which uses the CPU). Not only doesn't a `GLKView` need a `UIImage`, properly coded a single `CIContext` is there.

Comment: Yeah man dfd and @KevinBallard it worked,  however I’m still not understanding why this works and that didn’t(using direct CIimage)

Comment: The best guess on my part - instinct more that not - has to do with the *technical* definition of what a `CIImage` is. Essentially, it's **not** an image! It's a "recipe" instead (I'm grateful Apple introduced better analysis/debugging tool for this in Xcode 9, but I haven't used it enough.) Bottom line, I've always felt it's a crap shoot to convert the way you were. Involve the GPU as much as possible, it won't hurt!

Comment: The sample code on Apple's WWDC 2017 session 506 has an example of a CIImage being displayed in the view. It's converted to an UIImage and dispatched to the main queue. I am doing the same thing , but I also keep getting that same extent mismatch error message. Did you manage to figure this out?
[link]https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/506/[link]

Comment: I needed to convert it by using createCGImage to convert that into cgimage and passing in the extent.  Then convert to uiimage

Comment: Should the extent be set as the original size of the input UIImage or something like the size of the screen you are working with?

Comment: I reused the extent given after I crop the image

Comment: Perfect: correctedImage.extent. :)

Answer (score 10):

I ran into the same problem you describe. Due to some weird behavior in UIKit / CoreImage, I needed to convert the `CIImage` to a `CGImage` first. I noticed it only happened when I applied some filters to the `CIImage`, described below.

```
let image = /* my CIImage */
let goodImage = UIImage(ciImage: image)
uiImageView.image = goodImage // works great!


let image = /* my CIImage after applying 5-10 filters */
let badImage = UIImage(ciImage: image)
uiImageView.image = badImage // empty view!
```

This is how I solved it.

```
let ciContext = CIContext()
let cgImage = self.ciContext.createCGImage(image, from: image.extent)
uiImageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage) // works great!!!
```

As other commenters have stated beware creating a `CIContext` too often; its an expensive operation.

Answer (score 2):

`Extent` in `CIImage` can be a bit of a pain, especially when working with cropping and translation filters. Effectively it allows the actual position of the new image to relate directly to the part of the old image it was taken from. If you crop the center out of an image, you'll find the extent's origin is non-zero and you'll get an issue like this. I believe the feature is intended for things such as making an art application that supports layers.

As noted above, you CAN convert the `CIImage` into a `CGImage` and from there to a `UIImage`, but this is slow and wasteful. It works because `CGImage` doesn't preserve extent, while `UIImage` can. However, as noted, it requires creating a `CIContext` which has a lot of overhead.

There is, fortunately, a better way. Simply create a `CIAffineTransformFilter` and populate it with an affine transform equal to the negative of the extent's origin, thus:

```
let transformFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineTransform")!
let translate = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -image.extent.minX, y: -image.extent.minY)
let value = NSValue(cgAffineTransform: translate)
transformFilter.setValue(value, forKey: kCIInputTransformKey)
transformFilter.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
let newImage = transformFilter.outputImage
```

Now, `newImage` should be identical to `image` but with an extent origin of zero. You can then pass this directly to `UIView(ciimage:)`. I timed this and found it to be immensely faster than creating a `CIContext` and making a `CGImage`. For the sake of interest:

CGImage Method: 0.135 seconds.

CIFilter Method: 0.00002 seconds.

(Running on iPhone XS Max)

Answer (score 0):

You can use advanced `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` to draw your image in iOS 10.X or later.

```
let img:CIImage = /* my ciimage */

let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: img.extent.size)

uiImageView.image = renderer.image { (context) in
    UIImage(ciImage: img).draw(in: .init(origin: .zero, size: img.extent.size))
}
```